# Why 406 sending post request with both path variable and a request body

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, httprequest

I am writing REST APIs with Spring Boot. One of my endpoints handles POST request that consumes JSON request body. Meanwhile, another parameter is provided in the url.

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/cycle?&visit={visitid}",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = "text/plain")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public String persistCycleCount(@Valid @PathVariable Integer visitId, @Valid @RequestBody CycleCount cycleCount)
```

Entity `CycleCount` looks like this:
@Entity
@Table(name = "CYCLE_CNT_HIST")

```
public class CycleCount implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CYCLE_CNT_ID")
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DOOR_ID")
    private String activeDoorId;

    @Column(name = "VISIT_ID")
    private long visitId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "SAMPLE_DTM")
    private Date sampleDateTime;

    @Column(name = "SAMPLE_TIMEZONE")
    private int sampleTimeZone;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "SYS_CYCLE_CNT")
    private int systemCycleCount;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "CTRLR_CYCLE_CNT")
    private int controllerCycleCount;
```

When test the api by sending a request with following JSON to `/cycle?&visit=1`, I got 406.

```
{
  "activeDoorId": "d002",
  "controllerCycleCount": 15000,
  "systemCycleCount": 78000
}
```

Here is the Swagger output of the request:
[image]
When I tried to debug by setting a break point at the first line of the handler method, it did not even hit that line after I send the request.
I have other endpoints similar to this one which does not need a variable in url and they all work.  Why am I getting 406?

Answer (score 0):

1- Maybe you could change your approach, you can use a RequestParameter not PathVariable

2- For validate the RequestBody you can put a BindingResult for validation data, and you can show if your request has errors.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cycle",
    method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = "application/json",
    produces = "text/plain",
    params = "visit")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String persistCycleCount(@RequestParam("visitId") Integer visitId,
        @Valid @RequestBody CycleCount cycleCount, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        // Handler request errors
    }
    // Body method
}
```

Comment: Using `RequestParam` works. What do you need `BindingResult` for when you already have `@Valid` annotation to validate the JSON?